# Update custom ribbon action for existing addin/app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, ribbon

I am trying to update an existing add-in that is installed on a number of sites. It has an existing elements.xml file with a custom action that is registered against content types, and this works well. This is registered for the Host App.

My update includes another custom action, however when I perform the app upgrade on my site, the new action does not appear. I have tried adding it as a new elements.xml file, as well as adding the new CustomAction to the existing elements.xml file in the app.

If I remove the app and install it fresh, the new ribbon icon appears, so it seems to be only in an app upgrade scenario that this occurs. Does anyone have any pointers for this situation?

Other details:

- Office 365 app
- Visual Studio 2013
- Currently using app catalog but app is also deployed via Office Store

Thanks